# Next.JS using CSS Modules not working as expected in app/about/layout.tsx

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, next.js

I'm learning **Next.js** and having issues with **locally scoped CSS modules**.

I have an about directory and inside, I have a `layout` component and the styles I applied on the layout component is not been applied on the about page.

**layout.jsx:**

```js
import styles from "./styles.module.css"

export default function AboutLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <nav>About NavBar</nav>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        {children}
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

**styles.module.css:**

```css
.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

I have followed the [Next js CSS Modules docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/styling/css-modules) but my css styles is not getting applied.

**File Structure**

[image: File structure]

I am using **Next js** version `13.2.4`, **Node js** version `18.15.0`

Comment: Can you share `styles.module.css` as well?

Comment: @devpolo I have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: What can you see if you inspect the page?

Comment: surprisingly, there are no errors in the web browser console.

Comment: If you inspect the html, can you see the `<main class="main-id" …>`?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? You can put this on codesanbox or just create a git repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, I would like to explain.

I had to delete my whole project and start all over, this time with the flag `--experimental-app`

```js
npx create-next-app . --experimental-app
```